# Sum of sensitivity and specificity meaningful?

Tags: scoring-rules, sensitivity-specificity, rule-of-thumb

I came across an [article in the BMJ](https://ebm.bmj.com/content/18/1/5) that claims that a useful rule of thumb metric for assessing a medical test's performance is that the sum of specificity and sensitivity should be greater than 1.5 for the test to be considered useful.

It's only given as a rule of thumb, but I'm still not sure about it. Surely the usefulness of a test is too context bound for this to be even vaguely applicable, and a proper scoring metric would be preferable in just about all cases anyway?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wonder if this will get closed for being a subjective question. Rules of thumbs always have some subjectivity to them.

Comment: That is only a small part of the article taken out of context. In many applications sensitivity and specificity are required to be much higher than that before the test is thought useful.